# Perl, telnet, and output

Tags: perl, telnet

I'm having trouble finding out why my perl script isn't handling output appropriately.

So, the code (**Updated based on suggested changes**):

```
sub telnet_connection{


    my $targetHost = $_[0]; 
    #my $uname = $_[1];
    #my $pword = $_[2];
    my @listOfCommands = @{$_[3]};

    if($verbose){print "\t\tAttempting telnet connection to $targetHost\n"; }

    eval{
            $telnet = Net::Telnet->new( Timeout=>5, Errmode=>'return', dump_log=>"dump_log.txt", input_log=>"input_log.txt");
            $telnet->open($targetHost);
            $telnet->waitfor('/Username: $/i');
            $telnet->print($username);
            $telnet->waitfor('/PASSCODE: $/i');
            $telnet->print($password);
            $telnet->waitfor('/\>/');


            #for(my $j=0; $j le scalar @listOfCommands; $j++)
            for my $command (@listOfCommands)
            {
                if($verbose) { print "\t\tClient: " . $targetHost . " Command:  $command\n"; }
                if($verbose) { print "\t\tExecuting command: $command\n"; }
                my @output = $telnet->cmd($command);

                if($verbose) 
                { 
                    print "OUTPUT:\n";
                    print "@output\n"; 
                }
                logging($targetHost, \@output, "0");
            }
            $telnet->close();
        };
        if($telnet->errmsg)
        {
            logging($targetHost,$telnet->errmsg,"1");
            print $@;
        }
}
```

This is a method I wrote that takes four arguments, the target of the telnet connection, username, password, and an array of commands. *For right now, I'm just using the global usernames and passwords ($username $password respectively) because there was an issue with something else. $verbose is a flag that I pass, and in this case it's set to true. logging is another method I wrote to handle output accordingly, but with $verbose being true, I should see it on the console.* The code is able to authenticate, and run the commands, but my output isn't present. When I check the dump_log and input_log, the raw (and formatted) text is present, and shows that I'm actually executing the commands and seeing the output, yet, when I try to check the output, it comes back with a "":

```
Telnet to <targetIPAddress>
        Attempting telnet connection to <targetIPAddress>
        Client: <targetIPAddress> Command:  who
        Executing command: who
OUTPUT:
```

And I'm just not sure where to troubleshoot from here. I've looked through several of the stack overflow posts already on Telnet in Perl, but not much help was found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via Perlmonks, I discovered the issue. Details here:

http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1097296

In the declaration of the telnet statement, you must include the prompt so the command interpreter knows when the output of your command is complete (which runs via regex).

```
$telnet = Net::Telnet->new( Timeout=>5, Errmode=>'return', dump_log=>"dump_log.txt", input_log=>"input_log.txt");
```

Needs to become:

```
$telnet = Net::Telnet->new( Timeout=>5, Errmode=>'return', dump_log=>"dump_log.txt", input_log=>"input_log.txt", prompt=>'/\>/');
```

Answer (score 5):

> And I'm just not sure where to troubleshoot from here.

Well, you're missing the most obvious Perl trouble-shooting techniques. Add the following two lines to your program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You'll get a few errors saying that you haven't declared variables. Most of them are simple enough to fix. But the important one comes near the end. You have:

```
my @output = $telnet->cmd($listOfCommands[$j]);
```

And then later:

```
print "$output\n";
```

And:

```
logging($targetHost, $output, "0");
```

`@output` is an array. `$output` is a scalar. They are two different variables with no connection to each other.

A few other tips:

```
$telnet = new Net::Telnet (...);
```

Is better written as:

```
$telnet = Net::Telnet->new(...);
```

I know that the documentation for the module uses the former version, but it's a really bad idea and has a good chance of breaking stuff in the future.

Also, your loop:

```
for(my $j=0; $j le scalar @listOfCommands; $j++)
{
    # stuff using $listOfCommands[$j]
}
```

Is better written as:

```
foreach my $command (@listOfCommands)
{
    # stuff using $command
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I had completely forgotten about use warning and use strict. Wow. Completely slipped my mind. I re-enabled those, and fixed the components that you mentioned. I'll see where it gets me from there!

Comment: I've updated the code based on your suggestions (updated above as well), but still no change in behavior. The output comes back as empty, and the logging sub only prints the location of the array in memory (ARRAY(0xetc.)